# Sharpspring script not loading consistently on a Gatsby page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have this page created on Gatsby and I'm including this Script from Sharpspring in the Helmet component and it loads sometimes but not all the time.
Any ideas why this happens?

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDom from "react-dom"
import LayoutTemplate from "../templates/LayoutTemplate/LayoutTemplate"
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"

const Preferences = () => {    
  return (
    <LayoutTemplate>
      <Helmet>
      <script async type="text/javascript"  src="https://koi-3QNLLDDY3O.marketingautomation.services/client/form.js?ver=2.0.1" />
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    {`
    var ss_form = {'account': 'ACCOUNT_NAME', 'formID': 'MY_FORM_ID'}; 
    ss_form.width = '100%'; 
    ss_form.domain = 'app-UNIQUENUMBER.marketingautomation.services'; 
    ss_form.target_id = 'form1'; 
    ss_form.polling = true;
    `}
    </script> 
     </Helmet>
        <div id="form1"> </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
  )
}

export default Preferences
```

Answer (score 0):

The "sometimes loads sometimes not" is caused because of [React's hydration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/glossary/hydration/#what-is-hydration), meaning that if you force a rendering (pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> for example) the component is forced to render so the `Helmet` script is triggered.

If you use Gatsby's navigation (even React's because Gatsby extends its navigation from React) the `LayoutTemplate` may not be re-rendered if there's no need to.

If you are trying to use some persistent layout across your project, I'd suggest using [`wrapPageElement`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#wrapPageElement) or [`wrapRootElement`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#wrapRootElement) APIs.

Another hacky workaround is to force the rendering of the script function in each navigation process. This, depending on your scenario may suit you:

```
const addScript = url => {
  const script = document.createElement("script")
  script.src = url
  script.async = true
  document.body.appendChild(script)
}

export const onClientEntry = () => {
  window.onload = () => {
    addScript("https://koi-3QNLLDDY3O.marketingautomation.services/client/form.js?ver=2.0.1")
  }
}
```

*More details about `onClientEntry` API: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#onClientEntry*

Then, you can load the script using a `useEffect` or similar, as you wish.